# Is there any browser-based LaTeX IDE that can run on a personal server?

Tags: resources, software

I wanted to have a docker image with TeX Live to run it on a server and use it remotely. I have no problem in creating and using it. However, I wish to add an IDE that could be used through a browser. Something that I could use similar to overleaf but that run and compile on my server. Exist something like that or should I build it from scratch?

Comment: `ssh` + `vim` = done?

Comment: What exactly is the advantage of having latex in a docker image like this? I don't really see the usecase. Also isn't sharelatex/overleaf already available as a docker image?

Comment: You could install a local version of sharelatex: https://github.com/sharelatex/sharelatex

Comment: There is also a standalone API: https://github.com/sharelatex/clsi-sharelatex

Comment: @Skillmon, your solution is what I currently have and using, I want something more.

Comment: I didn't know that sharelatex has a docker image nor a local version. I think that these comments could be considered as the answer that I needed.

Comment: @gvgramazio more than `vim`? That doesn't exist editor wise.

Comment: @Marijn you were not pinged but ^^^

Comment: @Skillmon I don't want to start a debate about `vim`. I know that I don't actually need nothing more than a connection to the server and a tex distribution. I don't even need `vim` on the server because I could edit the file on my machine and compile it on the server. :)

Comment: @gvgramazio in which case you'd use `vim` on your machine, of course :)

Answer (score 2):

Overleaf (aka ShareLatex) can be run in a stand-alone server, according to this [GitHub page](https://github.com/overleaf/overleaf) (thanks to user36296).
According to this [guide](https://github.com/overleaf/overleaf/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide), it is simply a docker image to adapt to your needs.

But probably someone already did it?
According to the result to `docker search overleaf`, such image seem to exist:

`docker.io   docker.io/dcwangmit01/overleaf-docker-sharelatex   Sharelatex with plantuml and graphviz support`

I would start by testing that docker image, and then make my own when I'm getting serious about it.